# How to disable query cache?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

First of all, sorry for not 100% clearly questions title.
It is easier to explain with few lines of code:

```
query = {...}

while True:
    elastic_response = elastic_client.search(elastic_index, body=query, request_cache=False)
    if elastic_response["hits"]["total"]) == 0:
        break
    else:
        for doc in elastic_response["hits"]["hits"]:
            print("delete {}".format(doc["_id"]))
            elastic_client.delete(index=elastic_index, doc_type=doc["_type"], id=doc["_id"])
```

I make a search, then delete all the docs and then do the search again to get the next bunch.
BUT the search query gives me the same docs! And this results in 404 exception on delete. It has to be some kind of cache, but i does not found anything, "request_cache" doesn't help.

I can probably refactor this code to use batch delete, but i want to understand what is wrong here

P.S. i'm using the official python client

Comment: If you add a sleep() for 2 seconds after deleting all the docs, does it work?

Comment: Also, why don't you delete the entire index instead?

Comment: @Andrei sleep helps, so another clue for cache. Which cache? :) I don't want to delete all docs only some of them

Comment: No, it's not about cache. It's about the [refresh_interval and the _near_ real timeness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html#refresh-api) or Elasticsearch.

Comment: So, call `_refresh` after your code leaves the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you! if you make this an answer, i will accept it

Comment: Try using a scroll instead of repeated queries. It's more efficient as you search once and don't have to force a refresh. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using a `sleep()` after the deletes makes the documents go away, then it's not about cache. It's about the [`refresh_interval` and the *near* real timeness or Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html#refresh-api).

So, call `_refresh` after your code leaves the `for` loop. Also, don't delete document by document, but create a `_bulk` request where you delete all your documents in batches, depending on how many they are.